# Quicksort in place Python

Tags: python

I am extremely new to Python and i am trying my hand in Algorithms. I was just trying my hands in the in place sorting of an array using quicksort algo.

Below is my code . When i run this there is an infinite loop as output. Can anyone kindly go through the code and let me know where i am going wrong logically :

```
def quicksort(arr,start,end):
    if start < end:
        pivot = arr[int(start + (end - start)/2)]
        while end > start:
            while arr[start] < pivot:
                start = start + 1
            while arr[end] > pivot:
                end = end - 1
            if start <= end:
                arr[start],arr[end] = arr[end],arr[start]
                start = start + 1 
                end = end - 1


        quicksort(arr,0,end)
        quicksort(arr,start,len(arr) - 1)
    else:    
        return



arr = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
quicksort(arr,0,len(arr) - 1)

print ("The final sorted array:",arr)
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: you have to split your array according to the pivot

Comment: But the position of the pivot is not fixed in my code . I guess it can move around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion is wrong. After doing Hoare Partition, you should do :

- call quicksort from start (of data that being sorted) to index that run from the end, and
- call quicksort from end (of data that being sorted) to index that run from the start

So you have to create new variables beside the argument to maintain start,end and indices that move toward each other in the partition.

In order to not change a lot of your code, i suggest you to change the argument

```
def quicksort(arr,left,right):
    start = left
    end = right
```

and do this in the recursion

```
quicksort(arr,left,end)
quicksort(arr,start,right)
```